# Why am I receiving "plow.new has not been called yet" when trying to plot PCAs?

Tags: r, plot, pca

[This is the end goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/To0fa.png) however when trying to plot the code below

```r
plot(PCAloadings[,1:2], arrows(0,0,PCAloadings[,1],PCAloadings[,2]), text(PCAloadings[,1:2], labels=rownames(PCAloadings))
```

I recieve the following error:

```
in text.default(PCAloadings[, 1:2], labels = rownames(PCAloadings)) : plot.new has not been called yet
```

I am unsure how to resolve this issue or what it pertains to, any help is welcome.

EDIT: when trying to run line by line only the first line runs. When trying to run arrows or text lines I run into the same error

```
plot(PCAloadings[,1], PCAloadings[,2])
```

[This is the output from the first line alone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8Pm9.png)

Comment: please provide reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a syntax problem. Try

```r
plot(PCAloadings[,1:2])
arrows(0,0,PCAloadings[,1],PCAloadings[,2])
text(PCAloadings[,1:2], labels=rownames(PCAloadings))
```

Comment: Still receiving the same plot.new has not been called error :/

Comment: Are you able to execute the above code line-by-line? When does the error occur? How does `PCAloadings[,1:2]` look like? Please update your question.